# Change the pull down icon for React Native Calendars

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I am looking for a way to change the icon used to bring down the calendar view when viewing Agenda. I am using this component https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

Right now it's a small line, I'd like to replace it with a delta arrow or similar.

[image: Screenshot of my agenda calendar view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `renderKnob` prop as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars#agenda) to render your own icon

```
renderKnob={() => {return (/*Render your Icon JSX here*/);}}
```

Comment: OK thanks, i had assumed activity indicator would either be a loading GIF or the dots beneath days where there was data for that date. Perhaps the docs should be updated to be clearer.